# Chained Gradle task cannot read file generated by previous task

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have gradle task, `taskA`, which when run will generate a html file. Then `taskB` will try opening that file. When I chain these like:

```
./gradlew taskA taskB
```

Then `taskB` cannot see the generated file. Incidentally IntelliJ is open and does not see the file at the same time.

However if I run the commands separately, e.g.

```
./gradlew taskA
./gradlew taskB
```

Then taskB can see the file fine. Do you know how I might chain the commands with the effect of running them separately? I have tried using `clean` at the start of `taskB` but it does not help.

Comment: There is a bug in your code, which needs to be fixed. If you want help with that, you need to post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got it to work was by `cd`'ing back into the current directory.
This can be achieved with the following command, when you are in the correct directory:

```
cd .
```

This forces gradle to pick up any new files immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The way you chain task in Gradle is by making **taskA** depend on **taskB**.

You can do it as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'base'    

def file = project.file('shared-file.txt')

task taskA {
    outputs.file(file)
    doLast {
        // Create the file
        file.text = "Hello world!"
    }
}

task taskB(dependsOn: taskA) {
    inputs.file(file)
    doLast {
        // Print file content
        println file.text
    }
}
```

To clean up the file you can run **cleanTaskA** which will cleanup all outputs that **taskA** has defined. Or if you want to add the cleanup to the generic **clean** task then add **clean.dependsOn(cleanTaskA, cleanTaskB)**.